# force restart postgresql docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, timescaledb

I have a script trying to restart postgresql docker container:

```
DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME="timescaledb"
docker restart -t 1 $DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME
timeout 9000000s bash -c "until docker exec $DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME pg_isready ; do sleep 1 ; done"
```

However, this line (with any -t number)

```
docker restart -t 1 $DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME
```

Takes extremely large amount of time to shutdown postgresql. Generally I have to go to the screen container postgresql (I used screens to manage my orchestration). and press Ctrl-C to force it shutdown and enter

```
docker run -ti --user 1000:1000  -p 5432:5432 --name timescaledb  --volume=/home/ubuntu/pgdata3:/home/postgresql/pgdata --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dashdhwqehqwhhkshajdkh -e PGDATA=/home/postgresql/pgdata timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg13-latest;
```

Is it possible to complete this process of force restart without me entering into the "screen" and press Ctrl-C and restart manually?

A related question is posted here:
[postgresql docker ctrl C seems to be better than docker kill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75248066/postgresql-docker-ctrl-c-seems-to-be-better-than-docker-kill)

I wanted to find a way to mimic Ctrl-C shut down of postgresql.

Comment: Why do you want to restart de docker?

Comment: @iserranoe ehm... my work is very complex, including python calling a lot of parallel queries to the database, sometimes, there is a lot of stuck memory there, I cannot find any simple way to clear them other than restarting everything.... it won't shutdown automatically but I want to 'actively' restart it.

Comment: maybe `docker kill`?

Comment: @TmTron, thanks, would you like to post an answer telling how shall I use it?

Comment: @user Just read the [docker kill docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/) and make sure, that you understand what it is doing and why you should prefer stop/restart: https://superuser.com/questions/756999/whats-the-difference-between-docker-stop-and-docker-kill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `docker-compose up` to start your docker and add `restart: always` to restart the docker when it shuts down for any reason.

Example of docker-compose.yml

```
services:
   db:
       image: postgres:14
       restart: always
```

EDIT. Replying to your comment, maybe you could prepare a bash script, forcing the docker to restart every x minutes:

```
while true
do
   docker restart posgresql
   sleep 15m
done
```

Or, probably better, you could program a task in crontab:

crontab -e

```
15 * * * * docker restart posgresql
```

I'm assuming you're working with Linux

Comment: ehm... my work is very complex, including python calling a lot of parallel queries to the database, sometimes, there is a lot of stuck memory there, I cannot find any simple way to clear them other than restarting everything.... it won't shutdown automatically but I want to 'actively' restart it.

Comment: Thanks. I actually still wanted to perform active Ctrl+C force restart other than relying on scheduler. but I still want a programmatically/script way to complete the Ctrl+C, restart, process...

Comment: You could add `docker stop posgresql` to the script.

Answer (score 1):

ok, it seems this is sequence of command served my purpose. Thanks, everyone!

```
docker stop -t 120 $DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME
docker kill $DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME
screen -S i2 -X stuff 'docker run -ti --user 1000:1000  -p 5432:5432 --name timescaledb  --volume=/home/ubuntu/pgdata3:/home/postgresql/pgdata --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sahisahikqhwwkejkqwjehjhwqjh -e PGDATA=/home/postgresql/pgdata timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg13-latest;\n'
```