# postgresql docker ctrl C seems to be better than docker kill

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am productionalizing using docker postgresql on a very large project. Sometimes, I would need to restart postgresql manually. I tried 3 approaches to shut it down and then restarted later.

The 1st approach is 'I go to the screen container postgresql (I used screens to manage my orchestration). and press Ctrl-C multiple times to shut it down' This approach seems the best. Restarting seems to be smooth as well. The shutdown usually completes 1 minute or two but I have to be there manually.

2nd approach is

```
DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME="timescaledb"
docker stop $DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME
```

However, it seems it never completes.

3rd approach

```
docker kill $DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME
```

However, the restart seems to be pretty long with a large recovery process....

What's the best I can do, mimicking method 1 where I keep pressing Ctrl-C to terminate it? While I could smoothly restart it later?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem! Thanks!

```
docker stop -t 120 $DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME
docker kill $DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME
screen -S i2 -X stuff 'docker run -ti --user 1000:1000  -p 5432:5432 --name timescaledb  --volume=/home/ubuntu/pgdata3:/home/postgresql/pgdata --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sahisahikqhwwkejkqwjehjhwqjh -e PGDATA=/home/postgresql/pgdata timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg13-latest;\n'
```